# OCI: CLI json string complains of incorrect json despite copying example format

Tags: oracle, command-line-interface

I am having trouble supplying nsg ids in an oci cli instance launch command. Can you advise what is wrong with my json here. The example seems to be similar to what im sending

ovcaqe@ovcaqe-VirtualBox:~$ oci compute instance launch --generate-param-json-input nsg-ids
[
"string",
"string"
]

ovcaqe@ovcaqe-VirtualBox:~$ oci compute instance launch  --shape 'VM.Standard2.1' --subnet-id 'ocid1.subnet.oc1.phx.aaaaaaaafegowyev5kc6zikq46u23gnkwmrcukrzqrrz4wb54vtwpemkktka' --ssh-authorized-keys-file 'ossetest/usr/src/tests/pca_3x/CE/oci_keys/keys.pub' --nsg-ids [ "ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.phx.aaaaaaaarkrfpv43nlqoodyft2bai53gsgs6vj7e5e54xqpertuov6oq4moq" ] --wait-for-state 'RUNNING' -c ocid1.compartment.oc1..aaaaaaaacjoppgf66qyx45urlqffji6tj7ng7ioy2k7b66w5myzlsroxu46a  --availability-domain ruWb:PHX-AD-1
Usage: oci compute instance launch [OPTIONS]
Error: Got unexpected extra arguments (ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.phx.aaaaaaaarkrfpv43nlqoodyft2bai53gsgs6vj7e5e54xqpertuov6oq4moq ])

Answer (score 0):

You should provide it like this
-nsg-ids '["ocid1.networksecuritygroup.oc1.phx.aaaaaaaarkrfpv43nlqoodyft2bai53gsgs6vj7e5e54xqpertuov6oq4moq"]'